# Unable to create production release, and to promote alpha to production release as well, in the new console design

Tags: android, google-play-console

I uploaded an alpha release successfully but in the option "**promote release**" the "**production**" option is disabled and it says "**this track already has a draft release**" and on the other hand the "**create new release**" in the production release is disabled as well. To get rid of this mess tried the following options but didn't work either

close track, resume track, edit release detail (found no discard or delete option)

**1. production release disabled**
[image]

**2. This track already has a draft release while promoting release from Alpha to Production**

[image]

**3. No discard or delete option in edit release**

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you go to Production > Releases then you should find your draft release there and there will be a discard button.

[image]